# InvalidProtocolBufferException trying to get main module package id

Tags: java, daml

I'm trying to set up an app using java ledger api and based on the ping pong example. However, the method "containsModule" is throwing the exception:

InvalidProtocolBufferException.java
"Protocol message had too many levels of nesting. May be malicious. Use CodedInputStream.setRecursionLimit() to increase the depth limit."

on this line:

```
//parse the archive payload
DamlLf.ArchivePayload payload = DamlLf.ArchivePayload.parseFrom(getPackageResponse.getArchivePayload());
```

Can you please help on this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often the packages are too big for protobuf to digest. As suggested by the error, you can set the recursion limit explicitly, e.g.

```
CodedInputStream cos =
  CodedInputStream.newInstance(getPackageResponse.getArchivePayload());
cos.setRecursionLimit(1000);
DamlLf.ArchivePayload payload = DamlLf.ArchivePayload.parser().parseFrom(cos);
```

We'll fix the example, thanks for pointing this out.